# Prevent User Control's constituent controls from appearing in the controls collection

Tags: c#, collections, controls

I have a control that contains another control.  This child control is constructed and then displayed on the parent control by adding it to the parent's Controls collection.

However, this results in the consumers of the parent control being able to directly access the child control's properties.

How can I prevent this?

I did try hiding the Controls property but all you need do to avoid that is cast the parent control to type Control and the Controls property is accessible again.  Unfortunately the Controls property doesn't appear to be virtual either.

I just seems a little odd, from an encapsulation point of view, to allow everyone external consumer access to the internals of the control.

Comment: You can't.  You can access Microsoft's own constituent controls — see the NumericUpDown control as an example.

Comment: hmm ok.  So much for encapsulation then.